# I need SharePoint's Web Part Connections' radio buttons to give me an "all" option

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

So I'm using Web Part Connections to filter through a couple of lists. It all works perfectly, except that, by default, the filter shows all of the content. If you select one of the options, it filters the list and that is all dandy. But I need to figure out how to let the users see all of the items again, and I can't seem to find a way to display an "all" radio button just above (or below) the rest of the options. Anyone has any clue how to do this?

Thanks!
-V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OOTB filter web parts are very limited and this is one blindingly obvious example. You may want to look at 3rd party or Codeplex ones for better features.

Similar to xOn's answer what I've done in the past is to add a Content Editor Web Part to the page with a hyperlink called "Reset Filter" that just links back to the page - this reloads the page and removes the filter.

Comment: I guess thats what i'll end up doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, choosing a view (right hand side of toolbar) will remove the filter. Not the most intuitive thing, but that's sharepoint for you.